# Filter by Querystring

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I am looking for a way:

1 - I have a list A which has department names

2 - I have a list B which has employees of departments and it also has lookup field to the List A.

3 - I want to make a Links (Titles of department) list which should have URLs which would take the users to List B and filter by Department Name.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also SharePoint has filter behaviour built in to document libraries/lists. It's not extremely rich but if you are just looking for a simple filter this may serve your needs. For example if you navigate to:

```
http://mysharepoint/Lists/Tasks/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=Status&FilterValue1=Completed
```

You will see all tasks with a status = Completed

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Query String Filter Web Part: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/connect-a-query-string-url-filter-web-part-to-another-web-part-HA010250999.aspx